# Infinitely many natural numbers with only positive even digits whose square also have only positive even digits

Tags: number-theory

Recently I noticed that the natural number $2022$ consists exclusively of even digits and its square $2022^2=4088484$ as well, which is not that remarkable.
Nevertheless it got me thinking if there are infinitely many natural numbers with exclusively positive even digits whose square also consists exclusively of positive even digits? I was not able to find that many in the higher numbers. Clearly my example does not work as it contains a $0$ so no Zeros are allowed.

A number should look like this
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n 2a_k10^k
$$
whereas $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^n$ is a sequence of natural numbers (not 0 included).

Comment: When you say "with exclusively positive even digits", that means no (non-leading) zeroes at all, right? So 2022 and 4088484 wouldn't actually count?

Comment: Allowing $0$ as digit gives [OEIS A136904](https://oeis.org/A136904)

Comment: I don't think the OP is giving $2022$ as an example of what they are looking for; rather as the reason they started looking. But OP, you say you couldn't find "that many"; can you give us an example or two, just to clear up the confusion about zeroes?

Comment: Not allowing $0$ as a digit gives [A137103](https://oeis.org/A137103). Apart from a few small special cases, the general term seems to be $666\ldots 6668$.

Comment: Yes this sequence answers my question!

Comment: Can you prove that $22$ and $262$ are the only possible special cases not of the form $\frac23(10^n+2)$ - which would include $2$?

Answer (score 2):

As the question was clarified to say $0$ is not allowed as a digit, this is not an answer to the stated question any longer.

$2\cdot 10^n, n\in \mathbb N$ is an infinite sequence of natural numbers with your property.

Comment: "your property" includes "with exclusively _positive_ even digits". So this might not be an answer.

Comment: Yes, I just went with his own example.

Comment: I read that not as an example, but rather as the catalyst that got them thinking. But clarification as to what they are actually after would still be desirable.